# How to get all the nodes at a given path in firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

This might be a very simple question, but I am not able to make it. Because I am new to firebase and javascript, though searched a lot. This is the structure of my firebase database.

```
{ "messages" : {
"AGA Clinical Trials" : {
  "test" : {
    "-KbQDSG-3AXKjk1erhWO" : {
      "senderName" : "abc@xyz.com",
    }
  },
  "test-1" : {
    "-KbQECK7edEok0treaLCI" : {
      "senderName" : "abc@xyz.com",
    }
  }
}
```

}

What I want is all the nodes list of AGA Clinical Trials which is test, test-1. I am using this query the firebase.

```
var siteListref = firebase.database().ref('messages').child('AGA Clinical Trials')

    siteListref.orderByKey().on('value', function(snapshot){

        var userName = snapshot.val();
        console.log('user name', userName);
    }
```

Comment: You've included a picture of the JSON tree in your question. Please replace that with the actual JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

When you listen to the value event on a location, you get a snapshot with the value at that location. So in your case that snapshot will contain all the child nodes under `AGA Clinical Trials`.

You're probably looking for the individual child nodes, which means you should loop over the resulting snapshot:

```
var siteListref = firebase.database().ref('messages').child('AGA Clinical Trials')

siteListref.on('value', function(snapshot){
    snapshot.forEach(function(trialSnapshot) {
        var userName = trialSnapshot.val();
        console.log('user name', userName);
    });
}
```

The exact code in the `forEach()` iterator depends on the data structure under each child nodes, which you didn't include.

A more idiomatic way of dealing with child nodes in Firebase is to subscribe to child events. For example by listening to `child_added`, you can get rid of the `forEach()` loop:

```
siteListref.on('child_added', function(snapshot){
    var userName = snapshot.val();
    console.log('user name', userName);
}
```

Comment: I am able to get the value, the problem is I just want the node name(test, test1). My use case is to show a list of AGA Clinical Trials user. May be I am not getting right cause of my novice skill in javascript.

Comment: If you want the node's name, use `console.log(snapshot.key)`.